# Android: setting a partial background

Tags: android, android-layout

I'd like to achieve the following:

[image]

The trick is that I'd like to do this without adding the yellow part as a separate view. This is an issue because this would be a list item and adding an extra view for each item just to draw the background is something I'd like to avoid.

The size of the yellow rectangle can be anything from 0 to the size of the whole view. This is supposed to represent a percentage.

My idea was to extends the Layout and calculate and draw the background on the onDraw() method, but I'd like to know if there's a better/easier way. I tried to get a drawable and resize it with setBounds() but that did not work.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: "My idea was to extends the Layout and calculate and draw the background on the onDraw() method, but I'd like to know if there's a better/easier way." - That's about as easy as it gets. One width calculation, and one call to `Canvas#drawRect()`.

Comment: yeah, this what I did, thanks, wasnt sure about performance but I gues in the end "everything" gets drawn anyway

Answer (score -1):

I think you can set background and padding for it, then you just change padding of background dynamically.

So the idea:

1. Create drawable shape and set it to view
2. Use `ScaleDrawable` or `ClipDrawable` to change it

Comment: padding will apply to whole view not only to background.

Comment: Are you sure that padding of **shape** will apply to whole view?

Comment: yes look here http://android4beginners.com/2013/07/lesson-2-2-how-to-use-margins-and-paddings-in-android-layout/